# ¿Cómo obtener el campo que cambió después de una actualización? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero obtener el campo que se cambió en al momento de hacer una actualización.
Anteriormente solo tenía controlado el campo de IsActivo para Activar o Desactivar el permiso y eso lo guardo en una tabla de log, tengo lo siguiente:

En el if verifico si lo que viene en la variable es diferente a lo que se tiene registrado para saber que se modificó ese campo, puedo pensar que debo hacer esa misma validación para todos los demás campos, pero por separado e ir comparando cada uno, pero quería saber si existe una mejor manera para lograr esto, ya que en mi tabla de log quiero guardar un mensaje que diga "Se actualizó el campo Cliente" o el nombre de alguno de los otros campos que pueden ser:
dbo.Permisos (IdCliente,Operacion,Ejecutivo)

```
--Verfifico si hubo un cambio en el estado
            IF @IsActivo != (SELECT IsActivo FROM dbo.Permisos WHERE IdPermiso = @IdPermiso)
                BEGIN

                    --Actualización estado
                            UPDATE dbo.Permisos SET IsActivo = @IsActivo
                            WHERE IdPermiso = @IdPermiso;
                
                    --Verifico a que estado cambio
                    IF @IsActivo = 1
                        BEGIN
                            --guardo el evento en el log
                            INSERT INTO dbo.LogPermisos (IdPermiso,Evento,Descripcion,IdUsuario,FechaEvento)
                            VALUES (@IdPermiso,'A','Permiso Activado',@IdUsuario, dbo.GETDATENADII());
                            SET @mensaje='OK'
                        END
                    ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            --Guardo el evento en el log
                            INSERT INTO dbo.LogPermisos (IdPermiso,Evento,Descripcion,IdUsuario,FechaEvento)
                            VALUES (@IdPermiso,'D','Permiso Desactivado',@IdUsuario, dbo.GETDATENADII());
                            SET @mensaje='OK'
                        END


                END
```

Pero necesito validar también si hubo un cambio en otros campos de la tabla, ya que necesito saber el campo que se cambió para poder tener un mejor control en mi tabla de log.

De antemano, gracias DTB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La manera en que lo intentas no es adecuada, porque una actualización no tiene porque ser de una fila, puede ser de varias a la vez, y por tanto `@isActivo` no puedes predecir a que registro se refiere, y otros se te escaparían.

```
Create table dbo.Permisos(
id int primary key,
isActivo int,
idcliente int,
Operacion int,
Ejecutivo int);
```

Ahora insertamos unas filas.

```
Insert into dbo.Permisos (
id, isActivo, idcliente, Operacion, Ejecutivo)
values
(1,0,1,1,1),
(2,0,1,1,1),
(3,0,2,1,1),
(4,0,2,1,1),
(5,0,3,1,1);
```

**Output**

En las sentencias disponemos de `output` que nos aporta información sobre los registros afectados.

```
Update 
 dbo.Permisos
 Set isActivo = 1
    , Operacion = 2
    , Ejecutivo =3 
 Output 
      deleted.id as Old_id
    , inserted.id as new_Id
    , deleted.isActivo as old_IsActivo
    , inserted.isActivo as new_IsActivo
    , deleted.idcliente as old_idCliente
    , inserted.idcliente as new_idCliente
    , deleted.Operacion as old_Operacion
    , inserted.Operacion as new_Operacion
    , deleted.Ejecutivo as old_Ejecutivo
    , inserted.Ejecutivo as new_Ejecutivo
from dbo.Permisos 
Where id in (1,2);
```

[image: Res1]

Como puedes observar, en la `pseudo-tabla deleted`, tenemos los datos anteriores a la update, y en la `pseudo-tabla inserted` tenemos los datos nuevos.

Además tenemos las dos filas que se están cambiando en la sentencia y no una sola.

Si esta información la guardas en una variable tipo tabla, en la siguiente sentencia puedes almacenarla en el log.

```
Declare @table table(id int, isActivo int, idCliente int, Operacion int, Ejecutivo int)

Update 
 dbo.Permisos
 Set isActivo = 1
    , Operacion = 2
    , Ejecutivo =3 
 Output 
     inserted.id
    , inserted.isActivo
    , inserted.idcliente
    , inserted.Operacion
    , inserted.Ejecutivo
Into @table
from dbo.Permisos 
Where id in (1,2);

Insert into dbo.Logs .....
select * from @table
```

[Output en Update](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/06/13/clausula-output-en-update/)

**Triggers Update**

De la misma manera que output puedes usar un trigger.

```
Create trigger dbo.TrPermisosUpdate on dbo.Permisos
After Update
As
Begin
    
    Insert into dbo.Logs ---- nombres de las columnas
    Select xxx from inserted  

End
```

También dispones de las mismas *pseudoTablas* con la información anterior y actual.

[Trigger after update](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/04/15/trigger-que-es-como-se-hace-y-como-funciona-after-for-update/)

**Auditoria de Tabla**

O versionado de tabla. Es una opción muy interesante, pero solo esta disponible a partir de Sql Server 2016.

Aquí no tienes que hacer nada porque se encarga el motor de generar un detalle completo de la auditoria. Todos los cambios.

Como requiere de muchas más cosas, y esta sería una opción solo a detallar si te fuera interesante, te dejo un enlace sin más.

[Versionado de tabla](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/19/versionado-de-tabla-sql-2016/)